# Cleaning up Protractor stack trace

Tags: javascript, selenium, jasmine, protractor, end-to-end

**The Question:**

Is it possible to clean up the stack trace and leave only relevant frames eliminating everything `Protractor`, `WebDriverJS` and `Jasmine` specific?

**The Story:**

Let's execute this example test:

```
describe("SO test", function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.get("https://angularjs.org");
    });

    it("should throw a meaningful error", function () {
        element(by.id("not_found")).click();
    });
});
```

It would fail with a following stacktrace:

```
SO test should throw a meaningful error
  - Failed: No element found using locator: By.id("not_found")
      at new bot.Error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:108:18)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.js:676:15
      at [object Object].promise.Promise.goog.defineClass.invokeCallback_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:1337:14)
      at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.goog.defineClass.goog.defineClass.abort_.error.executeNext_.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:2776:14)
      at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.goog.defineClass.goog.defineClass.abort_.error.executeNext_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:2758:21)
      at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/async/run.js:124:15)
      at process._tickCallback (node.js:377:9)
  Error
      at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.js:382:21)
      at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function) [as click] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.js:78:17)
      at [object Object].ElementFinder.(anonymous function) [as click] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.js:711:7)
      at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/job/project/test/e2e/specs/test.spec.js:9:37)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:96:23
      at [object Object].promise.Promise.goog.defineClass.constructor (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:1056:7)
      at new wrappedCtr (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:2468:26)
      at controlFlowExecute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:82:18)
      at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.goog.defineClass.goog.defineClass.abort_.error.executeNext_.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:2776:14)
      at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.goog.defineClass.goog.defineClass.abort_.error.executeNext_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:2758:21)
  From: Task: Run it("should throw a meaningful error") in control flow
      at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:81:14)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:18:5
      at [object Object].promise.Promise.goog.defineClass.invokeCallback_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:1337:14)
      at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.goog.defineClass.goog.defineClass.abort_.error.executeNext_.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:2776:14)
      at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.goog.defineClass.goog.defineClass.abort_.error.executeNext_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:2758:21)
      at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/async/run.js:124:15)
  From asynchronous test: 
  Error
      at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/user/job/project/test/e2e/specs/test.spec.js:8:5)
      at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/job/project/test/e2e/specs/test.spec.js:3:1)
      at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
      at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

As you can see, it's not easy to find on which line in the test the error actually happened. It's hidden somewhere inside the stack trace covered by `Protractor`, `WebDriverJS` and `Jasmine` stack frames. This makes it difficult to debug and develop end-to-end tests.

**Desired output:**

```
SO test should throw a meaningful error
  - Failed: No element found using locator: By.id("not_found")
      at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/job/project/test/e2e/specs/test.spec.js:9:37)
  From asynchronous test: 
  Error
      at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/user/job/project/test/e2e/specs/test.spec.js:8:5)
      at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/job/project/test/e2e/specs/test.spec.js:3:1)
      at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
      at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
      at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
```

Using `protractor` 3.0.0 and `jasmine2`.

---

In `mocha` world, there is a relevant [`mocha-clean`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-clean) package that filters out everything coming from inside `node_modules` and `mocha` itself leaving a clean stack trace that is easy to read.

Comment: Do you use any custom reporters? I have a much cleaner result for the same test.

Comment: @MichaelRadionov just tried separately with a default config with no reporters - yeah, the result is different and more clean (though it still contain `selenium` and `jasmine` specific frames). You were right, looks like [`jasmine-spec-reporter`](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter/blob/master/docs/protractor-configuration.md) made the stacktrace worse. Please post an answer and I'll accept that. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelRadionov btw, taking aside `jasmine-spec-reporter` related issue, do you think we can clean up the stack trace even more eliminating everything node_modules and jasmine-core specific? So it would look close to what is under the Desired Output? Thanks.

Comment: I see in docs for [`jasmine-spec-reporter`](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter), that it has an option `displayStacktrace: 'none'`. Maybe it will hide everything?

Comment: @MichaelRadionov interesting, we've been using `all` and that's really too much of unnecessary information as we've seen in the stacktrace provided in the answer. I've tried `none` - this just outputs an error itself and nothing more. `summary` behaves the same as `all` in this case. In other words, `summary` and `all` throw the stack traces starting with `node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js` and not the line in the actual test itself. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelRadionov also, `displayStacktrace: 'specs'` behaves similar to `summary` and `all`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, if you use any custom reporters, they may introduce new behavior in controlling output of a stack trace. Protractor itself hides pretty much everything, so you won't see any log entries from node_modules or Jasmine.

As you use [jasmine-spec-reporter](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter), which provides an option to control a stack trace, it might be the case, that you have set some verbose mode in the options. In the [docs for Protractor](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter/blob/master/docs/protractor-configuration.md) for some reason it is suggested to use `all` mode, which basically displays the enitre stack trace.

```
    onPrepare: function () {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
      spec: {
        displayStacktrace: true
      }
    }));
```

If you simply change the option `displayStacktrace` from `all` to `none`, you should get clean results without any stack traces. There are also options `summary` and `specs`. You might not notice the difference between them in your example, but if you add a few more specs in your suite, then you'll be able to see the difference:

1. `specs` - if spec fails in the process of running tests, you'll see a stack trace for it immediately after a spec failure message
2. `summary` - if spec fails in the process of running tests, you'll **not** see a stack trace for it immediately after a spec failure message, but you'll get a list of all stack traces for failed specs in the end of all tests
3. `all` - combines `specs` and `summary` - if spec fails in the process of running tests, you'll see a stack trace for it immediately after a spec failure message **and** you'll get a list of all stack traces for failed specs in the end of all tests
4. `none` - stack traces won't be shown anywhere

Answer (score 1):

`jasmine-spec-reporter`'s API has changed.

The [new example](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter/tree/master/examples/protractor) illustrates a simple option to turn off stack traces:

```
let SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;

exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    // Your config here...

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    print: function () {}
  },

    onPrepare: function () {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
            new SpecReporter({
                spec: {
                     displayStacktrace: true
                }
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for a stable and convenient way to filter out Protractor stacktrace, there is one more option - [`protractor-beautiful-reporter`](https://github.com/Evilweed/protractor-beautiful-reporter) which would generate a very informative HTML report which also can filter out the stacktrace focusing only on the relevant parts ("smart stack trace" feature).

Answer (score 0):

you can set webdriver logging level by passing parameter --logging. 
For example, in package.json make it look like this

```
"start": "node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager start --logging=logging.conf"
```

create file logging.conf and place it in root folder of your project

and in this file put

> level=WARNING