# Protractor call stack specific to my code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am using Protractor to run some e2e tests on an Angular JS app (with a Node.js backend).

When an error occurs, is there a way to shorten the call stack so that only my own code appears?

This is what protractor outputs:

```
Message:
    Failed: Invalid locator
      Stack:
        TypeError: Invalid locator
            at Object.check [as checkedLocator] (/Documents/Work/blah/node_modules/gulp-angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/by.js:267:9)
            at WebDriver.findElements (/Documents/Work/blah/node_modules/gulp-angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:919:18)
            at /Documents/Work/blah/node_modules/gulp-angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:160:44
            at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/Documents/Work/blah/node_modules/gulp-angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1379:14)
            at TaskQueue.execute_ (/Documents/Work/blah/node_modules/gulp-angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
            at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Documents/Work/blah/node_modules/gulp-angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
            at asyncRun (/Documents/Work/blah/node_modules/gulp-angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2775:27)
            at /Documents/Work/blah/node_modules/gulp-angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
            at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)Error
            at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (/Documents/Work/blah/node_modules/gulp-angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:397:27)
            at ElementArrayFinder._this.(anonymous function) [as click] (/Documents/Work/blah/node_modules/gulp-angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:100:30)
            at ElementFinder.(anonymous function) [as click] (/Documents/Work/blah/node_modules/gulp-angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:728:22)
            at Object.<anonymous> (/Documents/Work/blah/tests/e2e/nav_spec.js:21:48)
            at /Documents/Work/blah/node_modules/gulp-angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:94:23
            at new ManagedPromise (/Documents/Work/blah/node_modules/gulp-angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1082:7)
            at controlFlowExecute (/Documents/Work/blah/node_modules/gulp-angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:80:18)
            at TaskQueue.execute_ (/Documents/Work/blah/node_modules/gulp-angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
            at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Documents/Work/blah/node_modules/gulp-angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
            at asyncRun (/Documents/Work/blah/node_modules/gulp-angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2820:25)
        From: Task: Run it("from home to cookie policy using footer links") in control flow
            at Object.<anonymous> (/Documents/Work/blah/node_modules/gulp-angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:79:14)
            at /Documents/Work/blah/node_modules/gulp-angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:16:5
            at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/Documents/Work/blah/node_modules/gulp-angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1379:14)
            at TaskQueue.execute_ (/Documents/Work/blah/node_modules/gulp-angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
            at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Documents/Work/blah/node_modules/gulp-angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
            at asyncRun (/Documents/Work/blah/node_modules/gulp-angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2775:27)
        From asynchronous test: 
        Error
            at Suite.<anonymous> (/Documents/Work/blah/tests/e2e/nav_spec.js:19:9)
            at /Documents/Work/blah/tests/e2e/nav_spec.js:4:5
            at Object.<anonymous> (/Documents/Work/blah/tests/e2e/nav_spec.js:38:2)
            at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
            at Module.load (module.js:487:32)

    8 specs, 1 failure
    Finished in 19.842 seconds
    [19:05:23] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
    [19:05:23] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
    [19:05:23] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
    [19:05:23] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
    [19:05:23] 'e2e' errored after 22 s
    [19:05:23] Error in plugin 'gulp-angular-protractor'
```

Instead, I would prefer to see:

```
Message:
Failed: Invalid locator
  Stack:
    TypeError: Invalid locator
        at Object.check [as checkedLocator]
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Documents/Work/blah/tests/e2e/nav_spec.js:21:48)
    From: Task: Run it("from here to there using footer links") in control flow        
    From asynchronous test: 
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/Documents/Work/blah/tests/e2e/nav_spec.js:19:9)
        at /Documents/Work/blah/tests/e2e/nav_spec.js:4:5
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Documents/Work/blah/tests/e2e/nav_spec.js:38:2)

8 specs, 1 failure
Finished in 19.842 seconds
[19:05:23] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[19:05:23] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[19:05:23] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[19:05:23] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
[19:05:23] 'e2e' errored after 22 s
[19:05:23] Error in plugin 'gulp-angular-protractor'
```

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049365/cleaning-up-protractor-stack-trace?noredirect=1&lq=1